# Pasting into cmd/powershell cuts off the first letter

Tags: python, powershell, cmd, sublimetext3

I just tried to paste some imports into a python shell and the first letters are getting "ignored".

[image]

You can see I tried on python and powershell, for some reason PS eats 2 to 3 letters.
Of course I get Syntax Errors on python so it's not visual.

Pasting it to sublime doesn't cut any letters off.

Answer (score 0):

From which Program are you doing your copy?

Which Version of Powershell you are trying?

Maybe there are some whitespaces or tabes in your Copy & Paste?

```
test = '''
import numpy
import time
import datetime
import os
import sys
import random
import threading
'''
```

Tried it in Pycharm and then copied in Powershell:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfRSz.jpg)

Powershell is Version 5.1.17763.316

You can find your Version with:

`$psversiontable`

Comment: CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.8793
BuildVersion                   6.1.7601.17514
PSVersion                      2.0

Comment: I'm copying from sublime 3, tried copy%pasting to this textbox and pasted back and got the same error but I just copied your imports and they went through fine.

Comment: Here's a screenshot of what I'm trying to copy, maybe it is the last sublime's update.
https://i.imgur.com/ktal2Az.png

Comment: And now I can't get it to fail. (•ˋ _ ˊ•)

Comment: Can be that it is depending on the latest Update. Or maybe the encoding settings of your Page are different? I was copying from UTF-8

Comment: I have no idea what was failing, haven't been able to reproduce again.
Maybe some line endings conflict between linux and windows?